# XElement XPathSelectElements C# Doesn't work for me

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml

I have XElement x

```
<projects><project><id>2</id><name>Project A</name></project>
<project><id>7</id><name>Blue-Leafed Project B</name></project></projects>
```

Than I am using the XPathSelectElements and expecting to get 2 nodes:

```
var projects = x.XPathSelectElements("/projects/project");
```

But `result = null;`

I was also trying to slightly change XPath

```
result = null;
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Nothing... BTW: What is `result`?

Answer (score 1):

What is most likely happened is that you loaded your document as an `XElement` and therefore `x` is already referring to the root node `projects`. Your queries have to be relative to that node and that node clearly doesn't have a `projects` child.  You're trying to select the child `project` elements relative to your `projects` node so your query should be:

```
var projects = x.XPathSelectElements("project");
```

Though in this case, you don't really need to use xpath, just use the `Elements()` method instead.

```
var projects = x.Elements("project");
```

You generally should use `XDocument` objects to load the document instead of `XElement`, otherwise you'd run into these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
var projects = x.XPathSelectElements("./projects/project");
```